# call DatePicker from helper class to an android activity

Tags: java, android, interface, datepickerdialog

Iam using DatePickerDialog in one of my activity and its working fine but now I have to implement it in many activities so I thought to put it in a helper class and extend that function to all activities as good code practice.I have created an interface but couldn't able to use it properly.I have seen another link on stackoverflow but over there they are extending from one class to another class not activity.What I want is I have a helper class where I have put multiple function which Iam using repeatedly in my app and then extend them to any activity according to requirement.So I want to put this datepicker function in HelperClass then then get this function any where in app.Thanku

This is my datePicker function which is currently Iam using in an activity and its working fine

```
public void datePicker(int day,int month,int year) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                }
                picker = new DatePickerDialog(RequestTraining.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {


                    }
                }, year, month, day);
                picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
                picker.show();
            }
```

This is the interface I made

```
public interface DatePickerListener {

    public void onDate(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, the best approach will be like this

```
class Utils {
    public void datePicker(Context mContext, EditText et) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }
        picker = new DatePickerDialog(mContext, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                et.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
            }
        }, year, month, day);
    picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
    picker.show();
   }
}
```

And now just call this method from any class like

```
Utils.datePicker(this, editText);
```

Comment: using this only show me the calender how should I get selected date in editText present in another activity

Comment: Changed the function, now you can pass, the editText to the function, and thus, all values selected will be shown in editText

Comment: thanku man it working,if I have to implement it using interface can you guide me that

Comment: Interface, would give you just an option to add a function name datePicker, but then you have to write the logic of datePicker again and again in new classes

Answer (score 0):

Just Need to make an interface *callBack* and implement it in all of your activities where you need callBack. Then you need to override the method *onDateSelected(String date)* in your activities which implements *callBack* interface. Just call the **Utils.datePicker(this)** where you want .

```
interface callBack{
onDateSelected(String date);
}
class Utils {
public static void datePicker(callBack call) {
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) 
{
                    final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                year = myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                month = myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                day = myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            }
            picker = new DatePickerDialog(RequestTraining.this, new 
   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int 
dayOfMonth) {
                    trainingDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;
                    call.onDateSelected(trainingDate);
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
            picker.show();
        }
}
```

Hope it will help you.